# EF Core and EF 6.x in Same project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I believe you can have both EF Core and EF 6 in the same project, however, I am having a hard time getting migrations working

the project started as EF4 and has evolved to EF6. Migrations are working fine.

I added EF Core because we added a new AspNet Core web site to the solution. Now I have a separate Context for Core.Identity.

has anyone actually done this in a real world production site, or am I just wasting time?

UPDATE:
Here is what I currently have.
One data project that has an EntityContext that is pointing towards EF 6, with a database that has 100+ tables.

I added a new website, an IT has an Entity Context that is using EF Core. I only care about the AspNet Core Identity.

Both contexts point to the same DB. I can now run migrations for each pointing to each contexts.

The problem is neither contexts knows about the other. If I have an object in the first context that needs to reference the AspNetUsers table, I cannot link it. My feeling is this cannot be done easily.

Comment: You can have them in the same SOLUTION, yes.  But not the same project.

Comment: How do I tell EF6.x to add migrations and update the database then tell EF Core to do the same?

Comment: Two ways: By command-line (the normal way) 2. You can programmatically execute the concrete-migration. Do you know HOW to do these? Your question makes it sound like you do. If not, reword the question so someone can answer it. –

Answer (score 0):

A kind of "linking" of both EF6 and EFCore contexts can be done, though you would need to decide what degree of coupling you're willing to live with. Here are some options:

**1. Use ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager**
Your EF6 entities would already have the user ids so you use `UserManager.Find` to get the relevant users into memory. You'd then have to match up entities in memory and this would only work if the user entity is accessible to both contexts (directly or indirectly). But the benefit is that your contexts will never step on each other and evolve independently with ease.

**2. Reference AspNetUsers in your EF6 context**
You would add a new entity and DbSet for your AspNetUsers, then create a new migration and delete all the contents from Up() and Down(). That would imitate a "database-first" for that entity so it doesn't get inadvertently updated. This increases the likelihood of concurrency issues - depending on your Identity setup - that you'd need to code in how to resolve. Also, you'd have to manually update the entity (and create more empty migrations) should there be changes. But the benefit is you can reference AspNetUsers table from your EF6 context with ease.

Anything more than sharing 2 entities or 2 contexts would make either of these approaches inadequate, and something like domain events would then be required.